# Dropzone geting previewTemplate on INIT method

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, dropzone.js

I have some problem ;[
My dropzone init:

```
<script>
      $(function(){

        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        $('div#dropZone').dropzone({
          maxFiles: 10,

          url: "<?=Url::to(['upload'])?>",

          init: function() {
            var thisDropzone = this;

            $.getJSON('img-list', function(data) {
              $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                var mockFile = { imgID: val.imgID, name: val.filename, size: val.size };
                thisDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                thisDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "/uploads/" + val.filename);
//                $(thisDropzone.previewTemplate).append('<span class="server_file">111</span>');

              });
            });

            this.on('success', function(file, json) {
              if(JSON.parse(json).success)
              {
                $.notify('Файл '+ file.name + ' загружен', "success");
              }

              $(file.previewTemplate).append('<span class="server_file">'+JSON.parse(json).fileID+'</span>');

            });

            this.on('removedfile', function(file) {

              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : '<?=Url::to(['del-img'])?>',
                data: {
                  fileID: $(file.previewTemplate).children('.server_file').text(),
                  _csrf: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(res) {
                  $.notify("Удалено", "success");
                }
              });
            });
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
```

ON **success** event, in every *previewTemplate* i appending **image-ID** (for deleting file on server vie ajax).

I'm trying add exists **thumbnails** ( getJSON construction. Method INIT()). But I can't delete added thumbnails ;[

[image]

Where i must to put **imgID** attribute?

Comment: your quest is unclear.. whether you need to save id to delete image ? if yes then do save ID i hidden field and retrieve when you want.

Comment: I'm append ImageID in every template (the only solution is to remove the images found). But on **init()** method i'm adding thumbnails, i can't to put ID for existing images (thumbnails)

Comment: why cant you.. you can select the ID's from table by having image names right ?

Comment: No. They are different. For many reasons. This locale and the server image has been renamed (to avoid dublicates). But dropzone canvas keeps old filename